# week of year starting at given date

Tags: android, calendar

It's kind of hard to explain but I need to start counting weeks after a given date. Then I have to get the current date and check what week number it is.

Already tried a few things and can't figure this out...
Thanks!

p.s. Maybe get the difference in days between two dates and divide by 7? How would I do this?

Comment: Show use what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method you mentioned of getting the difference would work fine. You'd just set the given date as one day of the year, and then get the current day of the year, using the Calendar class.

```
//Set Given Date to what you want it to be, eg 10th March 2006. (Months are indexed from 0-11)
Calendar calendarGivenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarGivenDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
            calendarGivenDate.set(Calendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2);
            calendarGivenDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2006);

//Receive the day of the year for what you previously set
    int givenDateDayOfYear = calendarGivenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

//Receive current day of year
Calendar calendarCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDateDayOfYear = calendarCurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

//Get difference in number of years
            int currentYear = calendarCurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int givenYear = calendarGivenDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int yearDifference = currentYear - givenYear;


//Find difference, divide by 7 (Round value down to get the difference in whole weeks)
double differenceDays = currentDateDayOfYear - givenDateDayOfYear + (365*yearDifference);
double differenceWeeks = Math.floor(differenceDays / 7);
```

Not sure if my math at the end is completely correct because I'm just trying to visualise it in my head, but give it a try? Hope this helped.

Comment: You would also need to set calendarGivenDate's year, and get calendarCurrentDate's year, then add 365 days for each year that calendarCurrentDate is ahead of calendarGivenDate.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6264/discussion-between-matt-harris-and-lorenz)

Answer (score 0):

The [java.util.Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class has all the methods that you need to do this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);
int weekNo = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```